# Why does this change to the makefile make the performance go up?

Tags: c, performance, makefile

I recently completed a performance lab in class, but there was one thing that my buddy showed me that I can't figure out why.
In the original makefile we had:

```
##
##

CXX =g++
CXXFLAGS= -m32 -static
```

But I changed the CXXFLAGS to:

```
##
##

CXX =g++
CXXFLAGS= -m32 -static -funroll-loops -O3
```

What exactly does the -funroll-loops -O3 do that the original doesn't?

Comment: `-O3` enables a bunch of optimizations. `-funroll-loops` is an optimization. Together, they turn on a bunch of optimizations plus one. Your program got faster when it was optimized because that’s the point of optimizations.

Comment: You should clearly consult the documentation for your compiler. `man gcc` and search for the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `man gcc`!

`-funroll-loops`:

> ```
>    -funroll-loops
>            Unroll loops whose number of iterations can be determined at
>            compile time or upon entry to the loop.  -funroll-loops implies
>            -frerun-cse-after-loop, -fweb and -frename-registers.  It also
>            turns on complete loop peeling (i.e. complete removal of loops with
>            a small constant number of iterations).  This option makes code
>            larger, and may or may not make it run faster.
> ```

`-O1`:

> ```
>       -O1 Optimize. Optimizing compilation takes somewhat more time, and a
>                  lot more memory for a large function.
>
>                  With -O, the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time,
>                  without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of
>                  compilation time.
> ```

`-O2`

> ```
>   -O2 Optimize even more.  GCC performs nearly all supported
>            optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff.  As
>            compared to -O, this option increases both compilation time and the
>            performance of the generated code.
> ```

`-O3`

> `-O3 Optimize yet more.`

`-O0`

> ```
>   -O0 Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected
>            results.  This is the default.
> ```

`-0s`

> ```
>     -Os Optimize for size.  -Os enables all -O2 optimizations that do not
>         typically increase code size.  It also performs further
>         optimizations designed to reduce code size.
> ```

`-Ofast`

> ```
>    -Ofast
>        Disregard strict standards compliance.  -Ofast enables all -O3
>        optimizations.  It also enables optimizations that are not valid
>        for all standard-compliant programs.  It turns on -ffast-math and
>        the Fortran-specific -fno-protect-parens and -fstack-arrays.
> ```

Hope it Helps!